# Incorrect Offset Scaling While Moving an Image Horizontally in Jetpack Compose Box

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, offset, image-manipulation

I am developing an Android application in Kotlin using Jetpack Compose, where users can upload an image, move it around (including zooming in by pinching with two fingers), and get the color of the pixel at the point of touch on the image.

However, I am encountering an issue when moving the loaded image from left to right (horizontally) within a Box.

The offset **(offset.x - topLeftX)** seems to increase disproportionately with the actual movement of the image on the screen. I've logged the offset change using **Log.d("Coordinates", "offset.x - topLeftX: ${(offset.x - topLeftX).toString()}")** and the values do not remain constant as expected when moving the image only horizontally.

```
Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                .padding(start = Dp(10.0F), top = Dp(60F), end = Dp(10F), bottom = Dp(10F))
                .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Black)) // Creates a border
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)) // Clips content to the shape
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                        offsetX += pan.x
                        offsetY += pan.y

                        topLeftCorner = Pair(offsetX, offsetY)

                        Log.d("Zoom", zoom.toString())
                        Log.d("Coordinates", "Top Left Corner: $topLeftCorner")
                    }
                }
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(onLongPress = { offset ->
                        touchLocation = Pair(offset.x, offset.y)
                        val topLeftX = topLeftCorner?.first ?: 0f
                        val topLeftY = topLeftCorner?.second ?: 0f

                        val relativeX = offset.x
                        val relativeY = offset.y

                        bitmap?.let {bitmap ->
                            val bitmapX = (offset.x / bitmap.width * bitmap.width).toInt()
                            val bitmapY = (offset.y / bitmap.height * bitmap.height).toInt()

                            if(bitmapX > 0 && bitmapY > 0){
                                var pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(bitmapX, bitmapY)
                                pointColor = bitmap.getPixel(bitmapX, bitmapY).toComposeColor()
                                val hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF and pixelColor))
                                Log.d("ColorPicker", "Picked color: $hexColor")
                                Log.d("Coordinates", "Top Left Corner FromBoxOffsetToLeftCorner: $topLeftCorner")

                                Log.d("Coordinates", "Top Left Corner Offset: $touchLocation")
                                Log.d("Coordinates", "offset.x - topLeftX: ${(offset.x - topLeftX).toString()}")
                                val width = size.width
                                val bitmapWidth = bitmap.width
                                Log.d("Coordinates", "Size.width: $width; bitmap.width: $bitmapWidth")
                                pickedColor = hexColor
                                showDialog = true
                            }
                            Log.d("Coordinates", "Touch LOCATION: $bitmapX; $bitmapY")

                        }

                    })
                }
        ){
            bitmap?.let { bitmap ->
                Image(
                    bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = "Picked Image",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()


                        .scale(scale)
                        .rotate(rotationState)
                        .absoluteOffset(x = Dp(offsetX), y = Dp(offsetY)),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                )
            }
```

Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here? Why is the offset not scaling proportionally with the image movement?

Comment: do you want to make your image draggable? you can do it using detectDragGuestures{}

Comment: I am developing an application that involves user interaction with an image using Jetpack Compose. Here are the key features I'm trying to implement:

The user should be able to move the image around within a bounding box.
The user should be able to zoom in and out of the image.
When the user touches a point on the image, the app should detect the color of the image at the touch location.

However, I'm currently having trouble obtaining the correct coordinates on the image after it has been moved.